# Pass object as redirect attribute from Spring to React

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, redirect

So, I have Spring (backend) and React(frontend). I want to redirect from Spring to React by passing some object or attributes NOT in the URL. I have next code:

```
    public ModelAndView receiveCallbackAuthorization(@RequestParam("code") String code) {
        ...some code
        ...
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + location, "info", userInfo);
```

On the React side, I got next:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  if (!props.location || !props.location.state) {
    // Redirect to another route or display an error message
    return <Redirect to="/error" />;
  }

  const { data } = props.location.state;

  return (
    <div>
      {data ? (
        <p>Data: {data.info}</p> // Render the received data
      ) : (
        <p>Loading...</p> // Show a loading indicator while the data is being retrieved
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Is it possible to do so, or maybe there's another way? The problem here is that I get a call on the backend as a callback, and after that, I need to process it and return it to the UI, which actually didn't ask for that.